# SQL Server Datetime newer than specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I use SQL Server. I have a column of type `datetime` in the following format:

```
2014-07-14 09:18:13.000
```

How can I write a `select` statement so that it only selects the dates that are newer than a specific date and specific date + time?

**EDIT**
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydatefield > '2014-07-22'

the datetime column: 2014-07-22 11:44:08.000

I get the data. I should not get the data because it says bigger than.

Comment: Did you try using `WHERE [column] > 'YOURSPECIFICDATAHERE'`?

Comment: A `datetime` column has no _format_. It just has a value. Your parameter should be a `datetime`-parameter. However, there are certainly a dozen duplicates on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For specific dates:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydatefield > '2014-07-14'
```

For specific dates and times:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydatefield > '2014-07-14 09:18'
```

Put the dates/times you want in the query.

Comment: Is not working. The data in the field says: 2014-07-22 and I write the same date in the query and stil get the data.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is - post your full query please along with what you want/expect to be returned.

Comment: You will get the data because without a time, it will default to '00:00:00.000'.  Change the WHERE clause to use the following day or add the time '23:59:59.999' to the date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from table where datetimecolumn >(select 'speicifdate' from othertable)
```

Comment: I dont't have the other date in another column. I would like to write it in the query.